# What defines the boot directory when using SFC to repair an offline system files

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

When using SFC (System File Checker) with the /OFFBOOTDIR parameter there seems to be little consensus as to how to identify the boot directory. I am trying to understand what defines the boot directory, e.g. what it contains, characteristics etc.

There are lots of articles explaining how to use SFC in this way, but they seem to largely avoid an explanation of this parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community. I am trying to gain a better understanding. There is no specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

With `/OFFBOOTDIR=D:` for example, `D:` is the current drive letter containing the target windows installation to repair. It should contain a `Windows` directory that you target with `/OFFWINDIR=D:\Windows` like:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d: /offwindir=d:\windows
```

If you boot from a windows installer CD and open up command prompt, the current drive letter will usually be `X:`. Other visible disk partitions will get assigned drive letters in whatever order they're discovered, so you may have to find which one is correct. For example:

```
# list the available drives and their letters
X:\>diskpart

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0         System Reser NTFS   Partition    500 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    237 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2                      NTFS   Partition    546 MB  Healthy    Hidden

DISKPART> exit

# I can see from the size that drive Ltr C is the bootdir I want
# check whether it contains the Windows directory:
X:\>C:
C:\>cd Windows
C:\Windows>
#success
```

If you can see the volume in diskpart, but it doesn't have a Ltr assigned, you can do that manually:

```
X:\>diskpart

# good idea to rescan if you're re-connecting a hard drive or something
DISKPART> rescan
DISKPART> list volume
DISKPART> select volume <number>
DISKPART> assign letter=Z
DISKPART> exit
X:\>Z:
Z:\>
#success
```

---

Not to be confused with the boot *partition*, which contains the windows boot manager/bcd and EFI/UEFI settings - usually labeled "System Reserved" and hidden

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Many websites suggest that System Reserved partition should be specified as the OFFBOOTDIR.

Comment: @SamBurn yes, that is incorrect. The SFC tool only knows how to scan and fix issues in the "Windows" partition. There are other tools like bootrec and bcdboot to troubleshoot and edit the "System Reserved" partition. If this helped, please consider marking it as the answer, thanks!